# How to access a dynamically generated id of a HTML element with angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

`<div  *ngFor="let link of links; let i = index;">
   <p>{{link.full}}</p>
   <button [id]='i' (click)="copyToClipboard(copy) ">Copy</button>
</div>`

How do I access the [id]="i" in my typescript file

Comment: Can you please provide us some context why you need to access this ID?

Comment: I need to change the text of the button, from "Copy" to "Copied". also I want to add a className of success

Comment: In that case there is no need to access the element by ID. Here's the Angular way of doing this: Set a propery in your component class `isCopied = false`. Inside the `copyToClipboard` method set `this.isCopied = true`. Then in the template you can change the button text as follows: `<button (click)="copyToClipboard(copy)">{{ isCopied ? 'Copied' : 'Copy'</button>`.

Comment: Correction (I forgot the closing brackets): `{{ isCopied ? 'Copied' : 'Copy' }}`

Comment: when a button is clicked it triggers the other buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this demo:

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-irxzeg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts]

It includes suggestions from @Sam Herrmann

And with Renderer, to add Class

[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjvvp1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add an `id` or to change 'manually' the label of button.

You can add a flag to know if link has been copied or not, inside your existing model.
For example:

```js
export type Link = {
  full: string,
  copied: boolean
}
```

Then, inside your code you can set this flag to `true`:

```js
copyToClipboard(link: Link) {
  link.copied = true;
  ...
}
```

In template, just use this flag to adapt the label of button, and also to set a specific class on button (or elsewhere):

```html
<div *ngFor="let link of links">
  <p>{{link.full}}</p>
  <button (click)="copyToClipboard(link)" [class.copied]="link.copied">
    {{ link.copied ? 'Copied' : 'Copy' }}</button>
</div>
```

```css
.copied {
  background-color: green
}
```

Comment: when a button is clicked it triggers the other buttons. why is this happening?

Comment: See the code I provided, `copyToClipboard` is called with the `link` variable. Same variable is used also to determine the correct label to display. So each link, and hence each button is independent.